# Socket.io check for inactivity apart from heartbeat from client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a PHP application that has a chat functionality using `nodejs` and `socket.io`.
What I now need to do is to log the user out if the user is dormant for more than 15 minutes.

The sessions are shared between the PHP application and `Nodejs` server. So `nodejs` server knows when a user last logged in or when his/her last activity was.

I am thinking of sending a `logoff` command to the socket.io client, and it would be really easy if I could distinguish between the heartbeat and a message from a client.

As the PHP application would only know about the activity of a user on a page reload or navigation, the user could still be chatting while he is dormant and PHP application won't know if the user is chatting. So checking the last activity of a user from session won't work.

So main question here is, can I identify a client which has only been sending heartbeat for more than 15 minutes (no emits) ?

Comment: Wouldn't the correct action be to update the session based on chat activity, and if there hasn't been any activity for 15 minutes log out on next heartbeat?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to log off based on chat activity is to have a simple timer that is reset every time the user is chatting. Something like this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // ...
    var logoffTimer;
    socket.on('chat', function() {
        // clear the timer on activity
        // should also update activity timestamp in session
        clearTimeout(logoffTimer);
        // set a timer that will log off the user after 15 minutes
        logoffTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            // add log off logic here
            // you can also check session activity here
            // and perhaps emit a logoff event to the client as mentioned
            socket.emit("logoff", { reason: "Logged off due to inactivity" });
        }, 60 * 15);
    });
});
```

Comment: Will need to modify this a bit to make it applicable for all the clients. In above code, any user's activity will reset the `logoffTimer`. That should be specific to the connecting socket.

Comment: @Broncha Hmmm. Are you sure? The `connection` event is triggered for every client that connects, and the `logoffTimer` is defined in that scope.

Comment: @MarcusEkwall this is perfect! Almost 3 years later and it is exactly what I needed, Thanks!